# admob and unity / crash

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, admob

Everything is fine in the console, but it crashes on the smartphone when the ad is requested.

```
InterstitialAd interstitial;

public void RequestInterstitial()
{
    string adUnitId = "from admob";
    interstitial = new InterstitialAd(adUnitId);
    AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder().Build();
    interstitial.LoadAd(request);
}

public void ShowInterstitial()
{
    if (interstitial.IsLoaded())
    {
        interstitial.Show();
    }
}

void Start() 
{
    string appId = "from admob";
    MobileAds.Initialize(appId);
}
```

Comment: Any error message, debugging records, description of your issue? Very low effort question imho.

Comment: @Rawrplus where i can take it

Answer (score 2):

my problem solved this:
Assets > Play Services Resolver > Android Resolver > Resolve 
Assets > Play Services Resolver > Android Resolver > Force Resolve